# Batch file RPG game error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
TITLE Zombie Warrior
setlocal enabledelayerdexpansion


:new
set playerdmg= 23
set zombiedmg= 24
set coin= 0
set rewards= 10
set level= 0
goto refresh
:refresh
set health=100
set zombiehealth=200
set zombie2health=400
goto menu
:menu
cls
echo.
echo Zombie Warrior
echo Coins = %coin%
echo.
echo 1) Play!
echo 2) Exit.
echo 3) Shop
echo.
set /p c=C:\

if "%c%" == "1" goto home
if "%c%" == "2" exit
if "%c%" == "3" goto shop
goto menu
set health=100
set zombiehealth=200
:home
cls
echo Welcome to the game!
echo -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
echo Coins: %coin% 
echo Level: %level%
echo.
echo 1) FIGHT!
echo 2) Quit
set /p c=C:
if "%level%" == "1" (
if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter2
)
if "%level%" == "0" (
if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter1
)
if "%c%" == "2" goto menu
goto home
set health=100
set zombiehealth=200
:encounter1
cls
echo You: %health%
echo Zombies Level 1: %zombiehealth%
echo Your damage: %playerdmg%
echo.
echo 1) Attack
echo 2) Run!
echo.
set /p c=C:\
if "%c%" == "1" goto attack1
if "%c%" == "2" goto refresh
goto encounter1
:encounter2
cls
echo You: %health%
echo Zombies Level 2: %zombie2health%
echo Your damage: %playerdmg%
echo.
echo 1) Attack
echo 2) Run!
echo.
set /p c=C:\

if "%c%" == "1" goto attack2
if "%c%" == "2" goto refresh
goto encounter2

:attack2
set /a zombie2health-=playerdmg
set /a health-=zombiedmg
if %zombie2health% lss 0 goto win1
if %health% lss 0 goto lose
if !zombiehealth! lss 30 set /a coin+=5
goto encounter1
:attack1
set /a zombiehealth-=playerdmg
set /a health-=zombiedmg
if %zombiehealth% lss 0 goto win1
if %health% lss 0 goto lose
if !zombiehealth! lss 30 set /a coin+=5
goto encounter1
:win1
set /a coin+=rewards
set /a level+=1
if level == 1 set /a coin+=10
goto refresh
:lose
cls
echo You lost :(
pause
goto refresh

:shop
cls
echo What would you like to buy? (type q to quit)
echo Coins: %coin%
echo 1) Baseball bat
echo.
set /p c=C:\
if "%c%" == "1" goto bat1
if "%c%" == "q" goto menu


:bat1
if %coin% lss 30 goto nope
set /a playerdmg+=5
set /a coin-=30
goto menu

:nope
echo You don't have enough coins!
pause
goto menu
```

So that is my code. What I'm trying to make is basically if I am level 1 or 0, it will make me go somewhere else.
For example if I am level 0
goto encounter1
if I am level 3
goto encounter4

But I don't know how to do that. I think I'm close in this line:

```
if "%level%" == "1" (
    if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter2
    )
    if "%level%" == "0" (
    if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter1
    )
```

Comment: Get rid of all of the spaces in the condition parts of your `if` statements.

Comment: Change `if  "%level%" == "1" (` to `if "%level%"=="1" (` and so forth. Batch if statements take white space literally, so you're comparing `"%level%" ` to ` "1"` instead of comparing `"%level%"` to `"1"` and it will always return false.

Comment: Another error: the syntax of the commandt is incorrect

Comment: You could be getting that literally anywhere. At least put _some_ effort into troubleshooting.

Comment: It still wouldn't work!

Comment: if "%level%"=="1" (
if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter2
)

if "%level%"=="0" (
if "%c%" == "1" goto encounter1
)

Comment: Please don't put multiple lines of code in comments; it's impossible to read.

Comment: @SomethingDark - `if "%level%" == "1" (` is perfectly valid syntax. Your advice is misguided.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm thinking of set commands, aren't I?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is stemming from these lines:

```
set playerdmg= 23
set zombiedmg= 24
set coin= 0
set rewards= 10
set level= 0
```

All spaces are significant in a SET statement, so your values include a leading space. Your `if "%level%" == "0" (` statement expands to `if " 0" == "0" (`, which of course is false.

Remove the leading space from the SET statements, and your immediate problem should be solved. (I haven't evaluated your entire code base to see if there are other problems)

A better way to structure your SET statements is to enclose the entire expression in quotes. The quotes mark the end of the assignment, but are not included in the value. This prevents inadvertent trailing spaced from being included in the value.

```
set "playerdmg=23"
set "zombiedmg=24"
set "coin=0"
set "rewards=10"
set "level=0"
```